# How is the axis of symmetry confirmed in this context?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the function:

$$f(x)=x^{2}-2x-8$$

It is demonstrable that the Axis of Symmetry of its map is 1 by halving the sum of the roots:

$$\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)$$
subsitute roots…
$$\frac{1}{2}(4-2)==\frac{1}{2}(2)==\frac{2}{2}==1$$

In this context it is claimed that:

$$f(1-h)==(h+3)(h-3)==f(1+h)$$

shows that the axis of symmetry is 1.  But how?

Comment: Are you asking how to show that $f(1−h)=(h+3)(h−3)=f(1+h),$ or are you asking how these equations show that the axis of symmetry is the line $x=1$?

Comment: Along with @DavidK, I also am somewhat unclear on what question that you are asking.  Therefore, I am unsure whether the following alternative approach is on point.  $$f(x) = (x-1)^2 - 9.$$  This re-statement of $f(x)$ automatically implies that $$f(1 + h) = f(1 - h) = h^2 - 9.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of symmetry $x=a$ of a parabola $f$ is the vertical line across which the parabola is, essentially, mirrored.

That means that if you go a distance $h$ away from the line on either end, to the points $x = h \pm a$, then $f$ should be same: $f(h+a) = f(h-a)$.

What this example has done is show this for the case $a=1$ on that particular parabola.